# Failure During Static Link of Version 0.3.3.5-rc

Tags: windows

I had previously built a static Tor lib on tag 0.3.3.1-alpha in MinGW previously with the following configure:

```
LIBS=-lcrypt32 ./configure --prefix=$PWD/dist \
                            --disable-gcc-hardening \
                            --enable-static-tor \
                            --enable-static-libevent \
                            --with-libevent-dir=$PWD/../libevent/dist \
                            --enable-static-openssl \
                            --with-openssl-dir=$PWD/../openssl/dist \
                            --enable-static-zlib \
                            --with-zlib-dir=$PWD/../openssl/dist \
                            --disable-system-torrc
```

This of course assumes I have statically built all those deps which I have. Now on tag 0.3.3.5-rc, I can successfully build using the same command. But when I try to link with my program, I get all sorts of errors like:

```
c:/my/path/tor-static/tor/src/or/libtor.a(main.o): In function `shutdown_did_not_work_callback':
C:\my\path\tor-static\tor/src/or/main.c:742: undefined reference to `tor_fix_source_file'
C:\my\path\tor-static\tor/src/or/main.c:742: undefined reference to `tor_assertion_failed_'
c:/my/path/tor-static/tor/src/or/libtor.a(main.o): In function `directory_all_unreachable_cb':
C:\my\path\tor-static\tor/src/or/main.c:1073: undefined reference to `log_fn_'
C:\my\path\tor-static\tor/src/or/main.c:1078: undefined reference to `tor_fix_source_file'
c:/my/path/tor-static/tor/src/or/libtor.a(main.o): In function `TO_ENTRY_CONN':
C:\my\path\tor-static\tor/src/or/or.h:1964: undefined reference to `tor_fix_source_file'
C:\my\path\tor-static\tor/src/or/or.h:1964: undefined reference to `tor_assertion_failed_'
c:/my/path/tor-static/tor/src/or/libtor.a(main.o): In function `check_fw_helper_app_callback':
C:\my\path\tor-static\tor/src/or/main.c:2202: undefined reference to `tor_check_port_forwarding'
C:\my\path\tor-static\tor/src/or/main.c:2207: undefined reference to `smartlist_free_'
```

This is when including (along with the deps) `ext/ed25519/ref10/libed25519_ref10.a`, `ext/ed25519/donna/libed25519_donna.a`, `trunnel/libor-trunnel.a`, `ext/keccak-tiny/libkeccak-tiny.a`, `common/libcurve25519_donna.a`, `common/libor.a`, `common/libor-crypto.a`, `common/libor-ctime.a`, `common/libor-event.a`, and `or/libtor.a`.

What library am I not including? Or is this a bug?

Comment: This might be due to the order of my libs in LD...still investigating...

Answer (score 0):

First MinGW has a current bug which can be solved, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47048#issuecomment-362892587), by downgrading some libs using:

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git-5.0.0.4745.d2384c2-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git-5.0.0.4747.0f8f626-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git-5.0.0.4741.2c8939a-1-any.pkg.tar.xz /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4741.2c8939a-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

You have to recompile everything once those have been fixed.

Then, I had my libs in a bad order. Assuming `%TOR_STATIC% is set as the base dir w/ tor and other deps beneath, here are a set of LDFLAGS, one per line:

```
-L%TOR_STATIC%/tor/src/or -ltor
-L%TOR_STATIC%/tor/src/common -lor -lor-crypto -lcurve25519_donna -lor-ctime -lor-event
-L%TOR_STATIC%/tor/src/trunnel -lor-trunnel
-L%TOR_STATIC%/tor/src/ext/keccak-tiny -lkeccak-tiny
-L%TOR_STATIC%/tor/src/ext/ed25519/ref10 -led25519_ref10
-L%TOR_STATIC%/tor/src/ext/ed25519/donna -led25519_donna
-L%TOR_STATIC%/libevent/dist/lib -levent
-L%TOR_STATIC%/xz/dist/lib -llzma
-L%TOR_STATIC%/zlib/dist/lib -lz
-L%TOR_STATIC%/openssl/dist/lib -lssl -lcrypto
-lws2_32 -lcrypt32 -lgdi32
```

Those flags will link in Tor statically to the exe.

Comment: Try using MSYS2 with it's mingw64 **and** make sure to assemble **all** the prerequisite libraries statically from source